# Check how many of a program are running via batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to check how many of a program are running via a batch file?

I made a program to use for tab for a cause and this is the code:
    `:1
    timeout /t 2
    start chrome.exe
    start chrome.exe
    start chrome.exe
    start chrome.exe
    timeout /t 7
    taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
    goto :1`

But this program sometimes open more than 4 copies of chrome before closing them, up to 8. Is there a command that I could use which will say how many of the program are open? kinda like the below:
    `@echo off 
    :1 
    start chrome.exe
    if "4 of chrome.exe are open" goto :2 else goto :1 
    :2 
    timeout /t 7
    taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
    timeout /t 2 
    goto :1`

I kept on getting errors saying that it is not formatted properly until I put in all the spaces where the code is, why do you have to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to treat chrome's processes because it normally creates a separated process for each plug-in (add-on). But answering your question:

> Is there a command that I could use which will say how many of the program are open?

Yes, you can see how many processes with same name are open at the moment:

`tasklist|find /c "chrome.exe"`

For using this within an `if` statement you can do the following:

```
for /f %%a in ('tasklist^|find /c "chrome.exe"') do (set chromeProcesses=%%a)
if "%chromeProcesses%" == "4" (do something...)
```

Comment: I did that, but `%chromeProcesses% = 8` with one tab open, 7 with two tabs open and 1 with no tabs open. I tried using the command on another computer, it said 6 with one tab open...? What you said is still the correct answer though, just need to change the numbers for each computer...